# Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
Sub search()
    Dim dato As String
    Dim filallibre As String
    dato = InputBox("Type 1 Or 2?")
    filalibre = Sheets(dato).Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If dato = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set buscado = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row).Find(dato, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not buscado Is Nothing Then
        ubica = buscado.Address
        Do
            buscado.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(dato).Cells(filalibre, 1)
            filalibre = filalibre + 1
            Set buscado = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row).FindNext(buscado)
        Loop While Not buscado Is Nothing And buscado.Address <> ubica
    End If
End Sub
```

I am getting error in my code when I run the macro, it works fine when I type "1" but when y put "2" it does the job which is moving the rows to the worksheet named "2" but it doesn't stops, seems like it stays looping until i press Esc then the message box with the error appears, the error appears to be in the line

```
Loop While Not buscado Is Nothing And buscado.Address <> ubica
```

how can i Solve this?

EDIT [6/7]

thanks a lot for your suggestions, I've tried some of your suggestions and seems like either i'm too noob for this VBA level or there is something completely wrong with my code, [here I is the link to my excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xvtoU3_RShfTWQO1n2x1anofxZaR86rK/view?usp=drivesdk) if anyone wants to test it and see if you can find the problem

Basically what the file does when I run the macro with Ctrl+Shift+K, is to ask as for either "1" or "2" then it identifies which rows have 1 or 2 in the column A and move those rows to the sheet 1 or 2 depending of what number I entered in the input box, it works well with "1" but not with "2"

Comment: Seems odd. Try just `Loop While buscado.Address <> ubica`.

Comment: Same result, i does the job but keeps doing the loop until i press Esc

Comment: hi. is dato a variable or the sheet name ? if its the sheet name it must be a string like sheets("dato"). good luck

Comment: hi, dato is a variable which takes the value you type in the input box

Comment: I can't replicate it. Do you have any other code in the workbook?

Comment: You need to use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module. The Variable you are using in `Dim filallibre As String` and `filalibre = Sheets(dato).Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1` are not the same, not to mention you declared it as a string but are using it as a long.

Comment: You should also specify a sheet name rather than `activesheet`. Otherwise you could be copying from 1 or 2 by mistake.

Comment: The boring truth is that your code works. You just need a bit more patience. It is quite slow (there are many more 2s than 1s) so you could look at standard measures to speed up code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot combine these two tests in one line:

```
Loop While Not buscado Is Nothing And buscado.Address <> ubica
```

If the first test fails then your code will still proceed to check the value of `buscado.Address` - it does not stop testing on the first False (ie. there is no "short-circuit" execution in VBA as there is in some other languages)

You can show this easily:

```
Dim c As Range

If c Is Nothing Or c.Address = "$A$1" Then Debug.Print "OK" '<< error

If c Is Nothing And c.Address = "$A$1" Then Debug.Print "OK" '<< error
```

**EDIT**:  @SJR is correct - there should never be a case where `FindNext` fails to locate a cell.  Once the initial `If Not buscado Is Nothing` test passes, all later `FindNext` will get a match, because `Find` always loops around when it hits the last cell.

I missed that the OP's error only occured when they hit "Esc", so in this case my answer (though technically sound as far as short-circuiting in VBA goes) does not address whatever is the underlying problem (that the OP's code gets stuck in a loop).

Comment: So `Loop Until buscado Is Nothing Or buscado.Address = ubica`

Comment: In two separate tests: eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099878/vba-cell-highlighting/12100537#12100537

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs - that has the same problem: neither `And` nor `Or` will short-circuit

Comment: Not sure that can be the problem because if `buscado Is Nothing` then the whole loop is bypassed completely, and nothing in the Do Loop is moving or deleting the found values. (See my comment and OP's response.)

Comment: @SJR remove the first test from the `Loop` statement and provide for an `Exit Do` within the loop. I made a revision to Tim's answer to show how this can be done. Cheers.

Comment: didn't read it that closely, was going to leave a comment on OP but felt it would be more easily understood by adding code snippet to your answer.

Comment: Am I missing something. How can it find it before the Do loop but then not inside the loop?

Comment: @SJR - you are not missing something: I was.  See my update above and thanks for persevering on that ;-)

Comment: Thanks Tim for that, glad I'm not losing my marbles.